# Plot pixel values that I already extracted from an image and stored into a txt file

Tags: python, image, plot, pixel

I am new to **Python** (I use **2.7** version) and I am trying to do some tests of a camera, and in order to do so I have to analsye the pixels of an image.

Here is the image: [Image of ColorChecker I want to analyse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbbZ1.jpg) (I have four other images in **.tif** format but it's not a problem I guess ?).

I have already wrote a code that takes the pixels and store them into a txt file.

Now, I don't know how to pute this data and **2D plot** it in order to vizualise the pixels (there is more than 1 million value in the stored list).

> size(all_pixels)
>   Out[10]: 1228800

Any help please ?

Here is the image:

```
    from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

 # Get the image
im = Image.open("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/IM.tif")

pixels = im.load() # this is not a list, nor is it list()'able
width, height = im.size

# Get the pixels
all_pixels = []
for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        cpixel = pixels[x, y]
        all_pixels.append(cpixel)

# Store the pixels into a txt file
thefile = open('C:/Users/admin/Desktop/testo.txt', 'w')
for item in all_pixels:
  thefile.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Comment: Do you want a 2D plot of the image pixels or line plot?

Comment: I want a 2D plot.

Comment: It is as simple as `im.show()`

Comment: Do you mean I should do all_pixels.show() ??

Comment: I just tried it and it doesn't work.

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: all_pixels.show()

Comment: Did I ever mention all_pixels.show() ?

Comment: @user128285what do you mean by "It is as simple as im.show()". Excuse me, I am new to all this and would appreciate an explanation.

Comment: You should literally use im.show()

Comment: I don't get it man. I don't want to show the original tmage I want to plot the values I extracted into a 2D plot.

Comment: When I just add im.show() to the code it dosen't anything when I run it.

Comment: You mean this?
plt.imshow(im)
plt.colorbal()

Comment: Did you read my entire question ??!!

Comment: I want to plot what is stored in "all_pixels" list in my code. I want to 2D plot it...

Comment: Ithink I just figured out how to do it:


`plt.plot(all_pixels)
plt.xlabel('pixels')
plt.ylabel('some numbers')

plt.show()`

Comment: It is called a line plot, not a 2D plot!

Comment: @user128285 Yes I mean this is not what exactly I want, but at least I am ploting the data, now I just need to plot this compared to some other values (reflectance in the Y axes) let's say reflectance is 1.0 all time. Any suggestions ??